# What is the italian equivalent word for disfranchise?

Tags: word-meaning, word-choice, translation, single-words

I was not successful in finding an exact equivalent Italian word for disenfranchise neither in Google nor in WordReference.

From the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disenfranchise) dictionary

> **disenfranchise** transitive verb:
>    to deprive of a franchise, of a legal right, or of some privilege or immunity *especially*: to deprive of the right to vote

In the [Wordreference dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/disenfranchise) I can only find

> Privare del diritto di voto.

Obviously this is a phrase that conveys the meaning of the word *disenfranchise*. However I'd like to know if there is a single Italian word expressing the same meaning.

Comment: Could you please add more context to your question and show some kind of attempt of translating it by yourself?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "disfranchise"? Took away the right to vote to some people?

Comment: “Disfranchise” (or “disenfranchise”) may have different meanings in English. Which one are you intending to convey in Italian and in which context? Words do not exist in a vacuum.

Comment: I think it has one meaning that is preventing one from voting rights. WordReference does not translate it well

Comment: http://www.wordreference.com/enit/disfranchise

Comment: I guess franchigia is the close root

Comment: What's the problem with the translations "privare [qlcn] del diritto di voto" or "togliere il diritto di voto a [qlcn]"? Please, edit your question to clarify your specific problem.

Comment: My question does not need editing imho. Just that having seen the phrase you mentioned, I believe it's rather closer to the definition than being a single word

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: Your question has received requests for clarification, been put on hold as unclear and been downvoted. So, apparently, yes, it seems that it needs some editing.

Comment: As to its meanings in English, they are far wider that just “preventing one from voting rights”. According to OED: “To deprive of the rights and privileges of a free citizen of a borough, city, or country, or of some franchise previously enjoyed”, then “To deprive (a place, etc.) of the right of returning parliamentary or other representatives; to deprive (persons) of the right of voting in parliamentary, municipal, or other elections” (the closer to what you say) and “To deprive of or exclude from anything viewed as a privilege or right”.

Comment: The thing is I explained more after you required clarification and got another negative vote.

Comment: Even if it has a wider meaning, nothing changes at this point!!! : are there single expressions in Italian that I don't know of? I just mentioned what I'm searching for. Other meanings are also welcome to be discussed. But just arguing on the question resolves nothing

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your question is simply “Is there a single Italian word meaning ‘privare [qualcuno] del diritto di voto’?”. If this is the case, I believe the answer is no, but I am ready to stand corrected if someone suggests such a word.

Comment: Yes! And there was no need for these unnecessary complications and giving negative votes

Comment: Because this was what I repeated in the question and the comments..

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question with more details and reopen it. If I have changed the intended meaning of the question feel free to correct it.

Comment: @DaG What you say is true, but in contemporary usage, especially in the US, *disenfranchise* means almost exclusively "prevent from voting"

Answer (score 3):

I think that the right word is **interdizione**, even if it has more meanings in Italian.

In Italy, in the legal field there are two cases in which the right to vote is removed:

- **Interdizione giudiziale**: for people are incapable of understanding.
- **Interdizione legale**: for those who have committed particularly serious crimes.

**From [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/interdizione/)**

> **interdizióne** s. f. [dal lat. interdictio -onis, der. di interdicĕre
>   «interdire»]. – 1. In genere, divieto, proibizione fatta da
>   un’autorità: i. dell’accesso in zone militari; trattative per l’i.
>   delle armi atomiche e nucleari. Con accezioni specifiche: a. Nel
>   linguaggio giur., esclusione della capacità di agire o dell’esercizio
>   di determinati diritti, che consegue a uno stato d’infermità mentale
>   accertata dal giudice (i. giudiziale) o a una sentenza di condanna (i.
>   legale; i. dai pubblici uffici; i. dall’esercizio di una professione o
>   di un’arte); chiedere, ottenere l’i.; pronuncia d’interdizione.

Comment: This is technically correct. My only perplexity is that I feel that “disenfranchise” is often used in English also to refer to people that are de facto deprived of voting rights (say, making it difficult or costly to vote; see, for some random examples, [here](https://scholar.valpo.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.it/&httpsredir=1&article=1136&context=vulr) and [here](https://www.kansascity.com/news/politics-government/article131138984.html)), while I believe that _interdizione_ only refer to to a legal measure, as adopted against a felon or someone legally incompetent.

Comment: @DaG right observation, but (I think) that in Italy there are no economic or political obstacles for the exclusion of the vote.

There is may be a voluntary deprivation of the right to vote that can be translated with disaffezione or  astensione.

Comment: I agree, in Italy we don't have that concept (I hope), hence we don't have a specific word. My remark was not a criticism; it was just to point out that if, while translating a text from US, one were to translate “dis(en)franchisement” with _interdizione_ some misunderstanding might result.